# pip install saws command not found

Tags: software-installation, pip

I'm trying to install saws https://github.com/donnemartin/saws on ubuntu, installation using `pip install saws` seems to work, but when I type `saws` it says

```
No command 'saws' found, did you mean:
```

I've tried also with sudo and restarting terminal, any idea?

Comment: What is the output of `pip install saws`?

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied: saws in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` amongs other lines with requirement already satisfied, the first time I ran it installed without problems

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's installing in your ~/.local/bin directory, which probably isn't part of your PATH. One thing you could do is copy it to a directory that *is* in your PATH, such as /usr/local/bin. Another way would be to add .local/bin to your PATH:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

You would need to put this in your .bashrc for it to execute every time you open your terminal.

Comment: As an aside, there has been a patch to do this for _new_ users in Ubuntu 16.04 and newer; see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/1588562.

Comment: @edwinksl I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 and the issue is still there